# How to sort this multidimensional array by points?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a script that runs through football fixtures, each day it will work out the teams played, wins, draws, losses, gd and points. At the end of each day it will upload the table to the database, so that I have a different table for each day (I have my reasons for it lol)

Problem is here is an example my code that creates the array.

```
if (array_key_exists(strval($firstDate), $matches)) {
// Matches Exist
foreach($matches[$firstDate] as $matchList) {
    $homeName = $matchList['homeTeamName'];
    $homeScore = intval($matchList['homeTeamScore']);
    $awayName = $matchList['awayTeamName'];
    $awayScore = intval($matchList['awayTeamScore']);

    $table[$homeName]['played']++;
    $table[$awayName]['played']++;
    // Check results
    if ($homeScore > $awayScore) {
      $table[$homeName]['homeWon']++;
      $table[$awayName]['awayLost']++;
      $table[$homeName]['points'] = $table[$homeName]['points'] + 3;
    } else if ($homeScore == $awayScore) {
      $table[$homeName]['homeDrawn']++;
      $table[$awayName]['awayDrawn']++;
      $table[$homeName]['points']++;
      $table[$awayName]['points']++;
    } else {
      $table[$homeName]['homeLost']++;
      $table[$awayName]['awayWon']++;
      $table[$awayName]['points'] = $table[$awayName]['points'] + 3;
    }

    $table[$homeName]['homeFor'] = $table[$homeName]['homeFor'] + $homeScore;
    $table[$homeName]['homeAgainst'] = $table[$homeName]['homeAgainst'] + $awayScore;
    $table[$awayName]['awayFor'] = $table[$awayName]['awayFor'] + $awayScore;
    $table[$awayName]['awayAgainst'] = $table[$awayName]['awayAgainst'] + $homeScore;

    $table[$homeName]['goalDifference'] = intval($table[$homeName]['homeFor']) + intval($table[$homeName]['awayFor']) - intval($table[$homeName]['homeAgainst']) + intval($table[$homeName]['awayAgainst']);
    $table[$awayName]['goalDifference'] = intval($table[$awayName]['homeFor']) + intval($table[$awayName]['awayFor']) - intval($table[$awayName]['homeAgainst']) + intval($table[$awayName]['awayAgainst']);


}
usort($table, function($a, $b) {
return $a['points'] - $b['points'];
});

} else {
// Matches Don't Exist
}
```

So the final array would be like

```
[Dover_Athletic] => Array
    (
        [name] => Dover_Athletic
        [league_name] => National League
        [competitionId] => 5
        [currentDateLeague] => 
        [position] => 0
        [played] => 3
        [homeWon] => 0
        [homeDrawn] => 0
        [homeLost] => 1
        [homeFor] => 0
        [homeAgainst] => 1
        [awayWon] => 0
        [awayDrawn] => 1
        [awayLost] => 1
        [awayFor] => 3
        [awayAgainst] => 4
        [goalDifference] => 6
        [points] => 1
    )

[Braintree_Town] => Array
    (
        [name] => Braintree_Town
        [league_name] => National League
        [competitionId] => 5
        [currentDateLeague] => 
        [position] => 0
        [played] => 3
        [homeWon] => 0
        [homeDrawn] => 0
        [homeLost] => 1
        [homeFor] => 0
        [homeAgainst] => 2
        [awayWon] => 0
        [awayDrawn] => 1
        [awayLost] => 1
        [awayFor] => 1
        [awayAgainst] => 2
        [goalDifference] => 1
        [points] => 1
    )
```

How would I be to order the array by 'points' -> 'goaldifference' -> 'name'.

I have looked at things like uSort, but because the second part of my array, is team names,and that I want to order by 3 increasing values. I can't find anything that seems to get me to understand how to do it.

Sorry if you know of a duplicate, I have had a search, but I haven't been able to find anything.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your question has missing code, and data for us to create an adequate answer to your problem

Comment: And format the array in a readable way please

Comment: Sorry the code is quite long, so just used a snippet to show how the array is created $table[teamname][key]. 

Have also updated the array so its readable.

Answer (score 3):

> This answer is tested on php 7.2

You can sort complex structures with `usort()`

```
 <?php

$teams = [
    'team1' => [
        'name' => 'Albertsens',
        'points' => 2,
        'goalDifference' => 2
    ],
    'team2' => [
        'name' => 'idkjustanameiguess',
        'points' => 4,
        'goalDifference' => 5
    ],

    'team3' => [
        'name' => 'another1',
        'points' => 4,
        'goalDifference' => 3
    ],

    'team4' => [
        'name' => 'rickross',
        'points' => 4,
        'goalDifference' => 2
    ],

    'team5' => [
        'name' => 'bigboss',
        'points' => 4,
        'goalDifference' => 2
    ],

    'team6' => [
        'name' => 'zoppa',
        'points' => 1,
        'goalDifference' => 3
    ],
    'team7' => [
        'name' => 'bertsen',
        'points' => 9,
        'goalDifference' => 6
    ],
];

$orderBy = ['points' => 'desc', 'goalDifference' => 'desc', 'name' => 'asc']; //just edit this to conform to your specification

usort($teams, function ($a, $b) use ($orderBy) {
    $ReturnValues = [true => -1, false => 1];
    $bIsBigger = true;
    $isAscending = 1;

    foreach ($orderBy as $key => $value) {
        $isAscending = ($value === 'asc') ? 1 : -1; //checks whether to go in ascending or descending order
        $bIsBigger = ($a[$key] < $b[$key]);  //does the comparing of target key; E.G 'points'

        if ($a[$key] !== $b[$key]) { //if values do not match
            return $ReturnValues[$bIsBigger] * $isAscending; //the multiplication is done to create a negative return value incase of descending order
        }

    }

    return $ReturnValues[$bIsBigger] * $isAscending;
});

echo '<pre>';
print_r($teams);
echo '</pre>';
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use uasort(), or else we will loose team key.

```
<?php

$teams = [
    'team1' => [
        'name' => 'Albertsens',
        'points' => 2,
        'goalDifference' => 2
    ],
    'team2' => [
        'name' => 'idkjustanameiguess',
        'points' => 4,
        'goalDifference' => 5
    ],

    'team3' => [
        'name' => 'another1',
        'points' => 4,
        'goalDifference' => 3
    ],

    'team4' => [
        'name' => 'rickross',
        'points' => 4,
        'goalDifference' => 2
    ],

    'team5' => [
        'name' => 'bigboss',
        'points' => 4,
        'goalDifference' => 2
    ],

    'team6' => [
        'name' => 'zoppa',
        'points' => 1,
        'goalDifference' => 3
    ],
    'team7' => [
        'name' => 'bertsen',
        'points' => 9,
        'goalDifference' => 6
    ],
];

$orderBy = ['points' => 'desc', 'goalDifference' => 'desc', 'name' => 'asc']; //just edit this to conform to your specification

uasort($teams, function ($a, $b) use ($orderBy) {
    $ReturnValues = [true => -1, false => 1];
    $bIsBigger = true;
    $isAscending = 1;

    foreach ($orderBy as $key => $value) {
        $isAscending = ($value === 'asc') ? 1 : -1; //checks whether to go in ascending or descending order
        $bIsBigger = ($a[$key] < $b[$key]);  //does the comparing of target key; E.G 'points'

        if ($a[$key] !== $b[$key]) { //if values do not match
            return $ReturnValues[$bIsBigger] * $isAscending; //the multiplication is done to create a negative return value incase of descending order
        }

    }

    return $ReturnValues[$bIsBigger] * $isAscending;
});

echo '<pre>';
print_r($teams);
echo '</pre>';
 ?>
```