# PHP Tournament system Team vs Team

Tags: php

I don't know how to achive team vs team system.
In other words, Team #1 has 6 points, Team #3 has 6 points, but because Team #3 won against Team #1 then Team #3 needs to be first on result, no mather what I have tried I can't figure it out how to make that possible.

First ordering is by points.
Second ordering is by team vs team, eg. Team #3 won against Team #1, and should be first.

```
<?php
    $matches[] = array(
        "team_1" => "Team #1",
        "team_2" => "Team #2",
        "score_team_1" => 1,
        "score_team_2" => 0,
    );
    
    $matches[] = array(
        "team_1" => "Team #3",
        "team_2" => "Team #2",
        "score_team_1" => 1,
        "score_team_2" => 0,
    );
    
    $matches[] = array(
        "team_1" => "Team #3",
        "team_2" => "Team #1",
        "score_team_1" => 1,
        "score_team_2" => 0,
    );
    
    $matches[] = array(
        "team_1" => "Team #1",
        "team_2" => "Team #4",
        "score_team_1" => 1,
        "score_team_2" => 0,
    );
    
    $result= [];
    $teams = array("Team #1", "Team #2", "Team #3", "Team #4");
    
    foreach($teams as $team) {
        $score = 0;
        foreach($matches as $key => $match) {
            if($team == $match["team_1"]) {
                if($match["score_team_1"] == 1) {
                    $score += 3;
                }
            } elseif($team == $match["team_2"]) {
                if($match["score_team_2"] == 1) {
                    $score += 3;
                }
            }
        }
        
        $result[] = array(
            "team" => $team,
            "score" => $score,
        );
    }
    
    $score = array_column($result, 'score');
    array_multisort($score, SORT_DESC, $result);
    ?>
```

Comment: Is this from some sort of course, or school curiculum? i have seen this exact same question before.

Comment: I was trying to do a project, but couldn't finish it because I was stuck with team vs team system.

Comment: the answer i linked has an answer by me tht can be edited to order layered structures. take a look at it maybe it will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save defeated teams history in $result:

```php
<?php
$matches[] = array(
    "team_1" => "Team #1",
    "team_2" => "Team #2",
    "score_team_1" => 1,
    "score_team_2" => 0,
);
    
$matches[] = array(
    "team_1" => "Team #3",
    "team_2" => "Team #2",
    "score_team_1" => 1,
    "score_team_2" => 0,
);

$matches[] = array(
    "team_1" => "Team #3",
    "team_2" => "Team #1",
    "score_team_1" => 1,
    "score_team_2" => 0,
);

$matches[] = array(
    "team_1" => "Team #1",
    "team_2" => "Team #4",
    "score_team_1" => 1,
    "score_team_2" => 0,
);

$result= [];
$teams = array("Team #1", "Team #2", "Team #3", "Team #4");

foreach($teams as $team) {
    $score = 0;
    $defeated = [];
    foreach($matches as $key => $match) {
        if($team == $match["team_1"]) {
            if($match["score_team_1"] == 1) {
                $score += 3;
                $defeated[] = $match["team_2"];
            }
        } elseif($team == $match["team_2"]) {
            if($match["score_team_2"] == 1) {
                $score += 3;
                $defeated[] = $match["team_1"];
            }
        }
    }
    
    $result[] = array(
        "team" => $team,
        "score" => $score,
        "defeated" => $defeated
    );
}
usort($result, function($result1, $result2) {
   if ($result1["score"] > $result2["score"]) {
       return -1;
   }
   if ($result1["score"] < $result2["score"]) {
       return 1;
   }
   if (in_array($result2["team"], $result1["defeated"])) {
       return -1;
   }
   if (in_array($result1["team"], $result2["defeated"])) {
       return 1;
   }
   return 0;
});
print_r($result);
```

Sandbox link is [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/266ac5a093131cf0370affeed5369e458e2312ed)

Comment: Oh yes, that is working. I am checking this in more detail now...
This should be it!

Comment: I have edited my message because I noticed I was the one wrong checking it. I didn't expect you to solve my problem I just asked you to point me in the direction that I should be thinking.

Comment: That's OK. I've deleted my comment. Btw, do you really think it's duplicated? I don't think so.

Comment: I never said it's duplicate I have even accepted your answer. I have only said that this question here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52910111/how-to-sort-this-multidimensional-array-by-points is simular to this, not duplicate...The question that is answered there is not team vs team, so it's not a duplicate.

Comment: I noticed close of your question and wanted to reopen this, because your question is different from acclaimed post. I looked into the post history and found out that it was you who accepted duplication :(

Comment: Can we change that? Because it just asked me if it was simular not duplicate :(

Comment: It's kinda hard. Open a question in meta stackoverflow, or contact moderators. But I think high rep users and moderators won't give much notice because this isn't such a difficult problem. Anyways, worth a try, or maybe not :P